npm run dev in laravel project webpack said . resources/js/app.js is missing
npm run dev in laravel project webpack said . resources/js/app.js is missing . but i downloaded this project and i want run in localhost . there is no such file app.js . in resources folder
am i missing something here??
here is looks like webpack code

mix.js('resources/js/app.js','public/js')
     .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png)$/i
                    // type: 'asset/images'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    mix.disableNotifications()

this is my first time i try to run laravel project locally
i did the php artisan serve command in another cmd . website running but it is stuck in loader
i wonder maybe i should run another cmd for webpack npm run dev command
i did but it gives 1  error that app.js missing

not sure I understand your issue. You say you downloaded this project but it does not have the resources/js/app.js file in what you downloaded but it is mentioned in your webpack.mix.js file. It's not clear if the problem is that you didn't download the entire project (e.g. with the app.js file) or there's a mistake in your webpack.mix.js in that it should not have been mentioning that file. Is this meant to be a new Laravel project?
